# How select data between rownum

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have data like in this fiddle [my query fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e0b26/1)

Whant select data which have rownum between 1 and 6 include, when I try between its already include data for example between 1 and 5. How to do it ?
Result must be :

```
2013    2013-12-24 09:02:38.000000  1100007 1937-06-17  1
2013    2013-12-24 09:02:38.000000  1100008 1937-06-17  2
2013    2013-12-24 09:02:38.000000  1100013 1937-06-17  3
2013    2013-12-24 09:02:38.000000  1100016 1937-06-17  4
2013    2013-12-24 09:02:38.000000  1100015 1937-06-17  5
2013    2013-12-24 09:02:38.000000  1100014 1937-06-17  6
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, PostgreSQL

Comment: You need to explain what you really want clearer. All of the rownum values are between 1 and 6, so you will get all rows regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want dates that have all six `row_num` values.  Assuming that you have no duplicate values of `row_num` for a give date, you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where row_num between 1 and 6) over (partition by date) as cnt
      from test t
     ) t
where row_num between 1 and 6 and cnt = 6;
```

In earlier versions of Postgres (or other databases):

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when row_num between 1 and 6 then 1 else 0 end)  over (partition by date) as cnt
      from test t
     ) t
where row_num between 1 and 6 and cnt = 6;
```

Comment: Yup. I just got that as well after I wrote my comment.

Comment: how it will be in postgresql 9.2? There is no filter